# Area 51 verification email does not arrive, nor can the email be edited

Tags: support, area-51, login, user-accounts, email

I want to commit to Area 51 proposals as well as propose a new site myself. However, I cannot do so, because I cannot earn the 50 reputation given by confirming the e-mail.

I am using Gmail and signed up on the main Stack Exchange site and confirmed my email. However, no matter how much I smash the Area 51 email verify button, I do not get email. I am getting messages from Stack Overflow, so spam filters are not the culprit here.

I cannot change my email either. Attempting to access the user edit page (In my case https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/edit/225873) results in a redirect to an error page "Oops! Something Bad Happened!". (https://area51.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/edit/225873) Is the Area 51 page being overhauled? When can we expect this to be fixed?

Also, I am proposing the removal of the need to reverify my email address after signing up on Stack Overflow or any other main site. The confusing separation turns away dozens of potential users.

Comment: @camerondiaz Also as usual only question (request) per question please

Comment: As to why the process is super convoluted and requires two email verifications, the simple answer is that Area 51 is based off a much older version of the SE engine; see [these comments](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29825/confused-by-a-message-about-e-mail-i-didnt-catch-am-i-okay/29917#comment45262_29917) for more info.